# URL auto add in POST

Tags: angular

The logged url is `192.168.0.26:8080/demo/api` but the actual request is made to `http://localhost:4200/192.168.0.26:8080/demo/api/auth/login`. I don't understand where does `http://localhost:4200/` come from and I would like to have it removed.

```
login(value) {
    console.log("enviroment => ", environment.apiBaseUrl + environment.path);
    return this.http.post(environment.apiBaseUrl + environment.path + '/auth/login', value)
      .pipe(
        tap(res => this.setSession),
        shareReplay()
      );
  }
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: I want to remove `localhost:4200/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apiBaseUrl` in the corresponding `environment.ts` file is probably missing the protocol part. Prepend `http://` (or `https://`) to it so that the `HttpClient` treats it as an absolute base url and not a relative one.